# Add Cell Numbers to Jupyter?

Tags: jupyter

Does anyone know a way to add cell numbers (not line numbers within cells)?  I have been using nbextensions for a while but it does not seem to have the ability to label cell numbers.

Comment: do you want to change the cell number for aesthetic reasons?

Comment: @Leevo I' like to be able to reference a cell, either to a colleague or in the narrative/descriptions.

Comment: This would also be useful for using nbqa to run linters and type checkers that report the cell number

Answer (score 1):

There is a cell tag feature. It allows any kind of label for individual cells, including numbers.

Cell tags are found in the "View" menu, then "Cell Toolbar".

Answer (score 0):

If you need it for a presentation, open the Notebook with a text editor, find the brackets where cell numbers fall and change them manually. If it's something you have to do once.